# Windbg: find the base module address of a driver object in kernel?

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, windbg

I'm trying to find the base module address of a driver object in kernel mode, its a malicious minifilter driver and the problem is driverentry and major function addresses a  seems to be fake(all 0s), I tried to look at the DRIVER_OBJECT structure using both DT command and the !drvobj 2 command, but non of them show where the module that this driver object is representing is actually loaded? lm command doesn't show it either, how can i find the base module address of a driver if i only have access to its driver object?

why there is no entry in the _DRIVER_OBJECT structure that shows the base module address of the driver?

output of dt command :

```
kd> dt _DRIVER_OBJECT 86b51448 
hal!_DRIVER_OBJECT
   +0x000 Type             : 0n4
   +0x002 Size             : 0n168
   +0x004 DeviceObject     : (null) 
   +0x008 Flags            : 0x12
   +0x00c DriverStart      : (null) 
   +0x010 DriverSize       : 0
   +0x014 DriverSection    : (null) 
   +0x018 DriverExtension  : 0x86b514f0 _DRIVER_EXTENSION
   +0x01c DriverName       : _UNICODE_STRING "\Driver\dumpx"
   +0x024 HardwareDatabase : 0x82dad250 _UNICODE_STRING "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM"
   +0x028 FastIoDispatch   : (null) 
   +0x02c DriverInit       : (null) 
   +0x030 DriverStartIo    : (null) 
   +0x034 DriverUnload     : (null) 
   +0x038 MajorFunction    : [28] 0x880b69e0     long  <Unloaded_crashdmp.sys>+19e0
```

Major function pointers also point to a different benign module!

Comment: [DRIVER_OBJECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_driver_object) is an opaque Structure and DriverStart  Member is not documented to be Accessible  check DriverExtension->AddDevice maybe